# Highcharts. Series highlighting not showing up in download

Tags: highcharts

I've been working on the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/d69otfmb/1/

```
function showSeries(e) {
    this.graph.attr("stroke", (e.checked ? this.color : '#ccc'));
    this.graph.attr("stroke-width", (e.checked ? 4 : 2));
    if(e.checked ==  true){
        this.group.toFront();
        this.options.enableMouseTracking=true;
    } else {
        this.options.enableMouseTracking=false;
    }
}
function highlightSer(chart){
    var series = chart.series, i;
    for(i=0; i<series.length; i++) {
        series[i].options.enableMouseTracking=false;
        if( series[i].selected==true) {
             series[i].options.enableMouseTracking=true;
             showSeries.call(series[i], {checked: true});
        } 
    }
}

var optionsChart1 = {
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container'
    },
.
.
.
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showCheckbox:true,
            events: {
                checkboxClick:showSeries
            }
        }
    },
.
.
.
}

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChart1,highlightSer);
```

I've set this up so I can use the checkboxes to highlight a series, and also so that only the highlighted series show up in the tooltip (through options.enableMouseTracking).

It works out pretty neat, but when it comes to exporting or downloading, any adjustments that have been made to the chart don't make it to the export server.

After checking many examples and reading the API a dozen times, I still can't make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to be using all built in highcharts functions. when you export highcharts is redrawing the image from the original options.

Comment: not really getting how the checkboxes work but this is a start. using these functions at least the exporting works

    function showSeries(e) {
      if(e.checked){
   chart.series[e.item.index].update({
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[e.item.index],
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[e.item.index]
    });
   }
   else{
    chart.series[e.item.index].update({
        lineColor: '#CCC'
    });
   }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing graphical attributes of the series without using Highcharts API. You would need to the same in the exporting callback to have colored lines. Anyway, you can use series update to correctly update the series which will be exported as you would want to.

Except of updating colors, you should update selected option as well.

```
function showSeries(e) {
  e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault()

  if (e.checked == true) {
    this.group.toFront();
  }

  this.update({
    selected: e.checked,
    lineColor: e.checked ? this.color : '#ccc',
    lineWidth: e.checked ? 4 : 2,
    enableMouseTracking: e.checked
  }, true, false)
}

function highlightSer(chart) {
  var series = chart.series,
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
    if (series[i].selected == true) {
      showSeries.call(series[i], {
        checked: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/0uxehybb/